# How to disable HTML transformation in TYPO3 8 LTS completely

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In TYPO3 8.7.8 LTS and a clean installation with the setting to create one blank basis page during install and the CKEditor extension disabled when you write something in a text element (I think it is the `tt_content`.`bodytext` field) it gets transformed (`<p>` tags added, line breaks removed etc...) even so there is no WYSIWYG-Editor enabled. So this transformation has to happen in the TYPO3 backend.

I'm trying to disable this now for a while but I failed so far. I tried the approaches from https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Rte/Transformations/Tsconfig/Index.html
And here mainly

> This configuration in "Page TSconfig" will disable the RTE altogether:
>
> RTE.default.disabled = 1

To be precise my `Page TSConfig` looks like this and the transformation still happens:

```
RTE.default.proc.dontRemoveUnknownTags_db = 1
RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db = 0
RTE.default.proc.exitHTMLparser_db = 0
RTE.default.disabled = 1

RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.proc.dontRemoveUnknownTags_db = 1
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.proc.entryHTMLparser_db = 0
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.proc.exitHTMLparser_db = 0
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.disabled = 1
```

So the question is, how can I disable the HTML transformations completely? Do I need to add something in the `TypoScript Setup` (I tried a bit but no luck) or do I have to do something completely different/in a different stop than the `Page TSConfig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at (and debugging) `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Html\RteHtmlParser` and here `RTE_transform($value, $specConf = [], $direction = 'rte', $thisConfig = [])` which seems to be the responsible function for the transformation of this field, I know that the transformations for my case happen in the mode `foreach`.
I also know that my `RTE.default.disabled = 1` wasn't in the wrong place. It was part of the loaded config, however at least at this point it has no effect at all.

What has an effect is setting `RTE.default.proc.overruleMode = none` or `RTE.default.proc.mode = none`. One would do it and any string which is not a registered mode works to disable any transformation.

IMHO: The TYPO3 documentation seems as messy as its code base, maybe `RTE.default.disabled = 1` has a use case somewhere and maybe you would find it if you would digg further into the documentation but I fear it may also just be an artefact from some old version which most of this pre- and postprocessing logic seems to be (and from what I've seen here in the last two hours I'm not confident other parts of this framework are 'modern', the mere amount of db queries for simplest backend tasks indicates I could be right). Anyways, my problem is solved and good luck to anyone who also needs to work with this reptile from the past for some reason.

**tl;dr: set `RTE.default.proc.overruleMode = none` in your `Page TSConfig`**